# Java appending new file's data to old file

Tags: java, file-io

In the first step am creating a file say test1.txt and adding records to it, and the rest records to test2.txt. Now i want to append the records of test2.txt to test1.txt. How to append them to test1.txt. The reason am dividing the files is i have a List with about 53K records, which am unable to write in a single file, as the buffer writer is closing as its reaching 52K.
The function am using for creating a single file is

```
    public void exportApprovedList() throws IOException {
    File approvedWhiteListFile = new File("/var/tmp/livecron/dictionary.common");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(approvedWhiteListFile));

    if (approvedWhiteListFile.exists()) {
        List<WhiteListTerm> approvedWhiteList = whiteListBO.getByStatus("APPROVED");
        for (WhiteListTerm whiteList : approvedWhiteList) {
            bw.write(whiteList.getTerm() + "|" + 
    whiteListCategoryBO.getById(whiteList.getCategoryId()).getCategoryname());
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
    bw.close();
   }
```

Comment: Just tried to write the entire list to single file, but the last records are missing, haven't started the appending part. Just checking how to start

Comment: Are you closing the file after writing?  Sounds like a buffer is not being flushed.

Comment: added the function am using  to my post. Can you please suggest me how to go ahead???

Comment: @prunge is right. You're not flushing and as a result the buffers are not fully saved to disk. Read this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/bufferedwriter.html

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, for the link to the article bufferedwriter. Therefore, i need to empty the buffer writer i.e., flush it before buffering more data. So, can i add line bw.flush() before the bw.newLine().

Comment: You need to flush it before exiting the program. Since you don't know when a program might exit, you need to call flush periodically if you want to avoid losing data. With BufferedWriters you should be able to add billions of lines/records (until you disk fills up) It appears your question is trying to work around what shouldn't be a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this....

import java.io.*;
public class FileReadWrite {

```
public void writeFile(String sorcefile) 
{
     try{
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sorcefile);
          DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
          FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("src/output.java",true);
          BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
          String strLine;
          //Read File Line By Line
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
          {
          System.out.println (strLine);
          bw.append(strLine);
          }           
          //Close the input stream
          br.close();
          dis.close();
          fis.close();
          fw.flush();
          bw.flush();
          fw.close();
          bw.close();             
            }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }
}
```

public static void main(String args[])
  { 
     FileReadWrite frw=new FileReadWrite();
     frw.writeFile("sorce file name wit hfull path");
  }
}